# Could not load file or assembly

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

I am using aws lamda function to connect my database and execute sql script file but whenever I run my project I am getting same error

I am getting this error in Lamda Mock Test Tool

Can anyone help me out..?Please let me know

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=16.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at AwsLamdaDb.Function.FunctionHandler(String input, ILambdaContext context)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at AwsLamdaDb.Function.FunctionHandler(String input, ILambdaContext context)
---------------- Inner 1 Exception ------------
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the specified file.
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingEvent(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingResolvingEvent(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not .NET resource, though I think this is due to improper installation of SQL Server SDK Assemblies. Can you check if the SQL Server SDK is installed or not?

Refer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/896e04a7-d5b0-41bf-a846-eb69dc5cc06a/microsoftsqlserverconnectioninfo-load-error?forum=adodotnetdataproviders